# SQL Get closest date, in both directions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out an efficient way of querying a table, i need to output the row closest to a given date, in both directions mind you.

I have a solution for the closest day in the future

```
SELECT  top 1 id
   FROM [dbo].[Shipments] 
   WHERE EstimatedArrivalDate < @date
   AND Complete = 0 
   AND (RegNoTrailer = @regNo OR RegNoTruck = @regNo) 
   ORDER BY EstimatedArrivalDate DESC
```

This gets the closest future date, but i need to check for past dates also.

Comment: What about add a `UNION ALL SELECT TOP 1 .... > @date ... ORDER BY EstimatedArrivalDate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this to be efficient, you will need the right indexes.  If so, I think a more complex query might be in order:

```
SELECT TOP 1 id
FROM ((SELECT TOP 1 id, EstimatedArrivalDate
       FROM [dbo].[Shipments] 
       WHERE EstimatedArrivalDate < @date AND
             Complete = 0 
             RegNoTrailer = @regNo
       ORDER BY EstimatedArrivalDate DESC
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT TOP 1 id, EstimatedArrivalDate
       FROM [dbo].[Shipments] 
       WHERE EstimatedArrivalDate < @date AND
             Complete = 0 
             RegNoTruck = @regNo 
       ORDER BY EstimatedArrivalDate DESC
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT TOP 1 id, EstimatedArrivalDate
       FROM [dbo].[Shipments] 
       WHERE EstimatedArrivalDate > @date AND
             Complete = 0 
             RegNoTrailer = @regNo
       ORDER BY EstimatedArrivalDate ASC
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT TOP 1 id, EstimatedArrivalDate
       FROM [dbo].[Shipments] 
       WHERE EstimatedArrivalDate > @date AND
             Complete = 0 
             RegNoTruck = @regNo 
       ORDER BY EstimatedArrivalDate ASC
      )
     )
ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(second, EstimatedArrivalDate, @Date));
```

For this query, you want two indexes:  `Shipments(RegNoTruck, Complete, EstimatedArrivalDate)` and `Shipments(RegNoTrailer, Complete, EstimatedArrivalDate)`.

By splitting the `OR` conditions into two separate subqueries, each subquery can use a different index.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly after a few syntax fixes :) thank you

Comment: O.o I wonder if it is this as inefficient as it looks, or if preparing it condenses it to something more coherent. Something tells me this isn't how SQL is intended to be used.

Comment: @Dmitry . . . This structure of the query allows indexes to be used to reduce the data set for the four cases implied by the original query.  There are more concise ways to express the logic; this version happens to allow the optimizer to readily use available indexes efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `Datediff` and `Abs` in combination.

```
select abs(DATEDIFF(second,<dateColumn>,<dateParameter>)) result,<otherColumns> 
from <tableName> order by  result
```

The first record will be the closest one.

Comment: Like i asked Raphael, would this not be rather inefficient in larger tables?

Comment: @JonasOlesen Of course there will be performance hit because you will be doing table scan all the time (unless there is index on other columns in the where clause). Alternate option is to make use of unions as in other response but that will involve multiple query executions. You can compare the two and evaluate for yourself. Also, Datediff did behaved badly earlier. Not sure if that has changed \.

Answer (score 1):

Try using DATEDIFF function to find difference between 2 dates. You would also need to add the ABS() function to cater for both past and future dates

```
SELECT  top 1 id
   FROM [dbo].[Shipments] 
   WHERE Complete = 0 
   AND (RegNoTrailer = @regNo OR RegNoTruck = @regNo) 
   ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(D,EstimatedArrivalDate,@date)) ASC
```

Comment: How effecient would running datediff on a large table be?

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
   SELECT  top 1 id
   FROM [dbo].[Shipments] 
   WHERE EstimatedArrivalDate > @date --change to >
   AND Complete = 0 
   AND (RegNoTrailer = @regNo OR RegNoTruck = @regNo) 
   ORDER BY EstimatedArrivalDate ASC --change to ASC
```

Or both together using `UNION`

```
SELECT  top 1 id
   FROM [dbo].[Shipments] 
   WHERE EstimatedArrivalDate < @date
   AND Complete = 0 
   AND (RegNoTrailer = @regNo OR RegNoTruck = @regNo) 
   ORDER BY EstimatedArrivalDate DESC
UNION
   SELECT  top 1 id
   FROM [dbo].[Shipments] 
   WHERE EstimatedArrivalDate > @date --change to >
   AND Complete = 0 
   AND (RegNoTrailer = @regNo OR RegNoTruck = @regNo) 
   ORDER BY EstimatedArrivalDate ASC --change to ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DATEDIFF() and ABS() to get the closest date difference

```
SELECT  top 1 id
   FROM [dbo].[Shipments] 
   WHERE Complete = 0 
   AND (RegNoTrailer = @regNo OR RegNoTruck = @regNo) 
   ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(SECOND, @date, EstimatedArrivalDate))
```